# In ARM Assembly, why are my values not updating?

Tags: pointers, assembly, arm, stack, cpu-registers

I am working on a simple ATM Machine. The issue I am having is:

```
        areFundsAvailable:
            cmp r8, r4
            ble fundsNotAvailable
            sub r8, r8, r4

    subtractTwenties:
            sub r4, r4, #20
            cmp r4, #10
            ble subtractTens
            sub r7, r7, #1
            b subtractTwenties

    subtractTens:
            cmp r4, #0
            beq withdrawComplete
            sub r4, #10
            b subtractTens
```

---

My Inventory:

```
getInventory:   
push {r4, lr}
        ldr r5, =total  
        ldr r8, [r5]    
        ldr r5, =inventory20
        ldr r7, [r5]
        ldr r5, =inventory10    
        ldr r6, [r5]
        ldr r5, =transactionLimit
        ldr r9, [r5]

sumTwenties:
        cmp r7, #0
        ble sumTens 
        add r8, r8, #20
        sub r7, r7, #1
        b sumTwenties               

sumTens:        
        cmp r6, #0
        ble loopDone
        add r8, r8, #10
        sub r6, r6, #1
        b sumTens

        ldr r5, =total
        str r8, [r5]
loopDone:


pop {r4, pc}
```

My Issue:

I am asking a user to enter an amount to withdraw. The ATM is limited to maximum transactions in a session, holds a set value of 20 dollar bills and 10 dollar bills so eventually it can run out of money.

I've done a good bit of the implementation, like making sure they only enter a value between 0-200, it's a multiple of 10.

I also can call my secret code, which does display my current inventory.

I am trying to work through my first transaction, by asking to withdraw, let's say $40. I need to make sure the withdrawal is approved, which works. Then I need to make sure I give them all 20s first, then 10s, if they selected a withdrawal like $50 for example.

I am running GDB, and noticing the register which is storing the total value (1500) is getting updated and deducted (1460) but my registers that hold my 20s and 10s are displaying 0.

This means I am not loading the registers or I am having some kind of issue I can't wrap my head around. 
I've pasted some of the more important pieces of code to see if I could get some feedback.

I do know this is an issue with me pushing and popping the stack, but I am getting lost.

Edit:
Register 7 has 50 20s by default
Register 6 has 50 10s by default

### Register 8 is the sum of 6 and 7 = 1500

Upon putting breakpoint
My registers are showing:
R7 : 0
R6: 0
R8: 1460

I should be seeing

R7: 48
R6: 50

Second edit:

Putting a breakpoint on my function withdrawRequestApproved, I am noticing the value is holding the WithdrawInput correctly.

```
    withdrawRequestApproved:
        ldr r0, =amountRequested
        mov r1, r4
        bl printf
        bl getInventory

checkTransactionLimit:
        add r9, r9, #1
        cmp r9, #10
        bgt transactionLimitReached


areFundsAvailable:
        cmp r8, r4
        ble fundsNotAvailable
        sub r8, r8, r4
```

calling bl getInventory is loading my total, but I am not loading my 20s and 10s. Also, I am losing my register 4 value after this function as well.

Comment: The `sumTwenties` loop doesn't finish until `r7` <= 0. Similarly for `sumTens` and `r6`. So I'm not sure why you're expecting 50 and 48(?).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Michael 

I noticed that piece of code was wiping out my inventory before it even started.
By deleting it, It worked fine.

Not sure what I was trying to accomplish when I first wrote that.